# How to bind the value from textbox to datagrid and datagrid to textbox in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

i have a datagrid, need to bind the value from textbox to datagrid using add button,
If i double click the datagrid the values want to bind in textbox. after modify the data in text box i need to replace the value for existing data in datagrid.

Comment: And what did you tried to do untill now?

Answer (score 0):

Like this for textbox to datagrid

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtLocation" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Location") %>' />
```